# User-Friend Relationship model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, social-networking

I am a new Rails developer and i am attempting to model a User-Friends relationship(Facebook style) such as it has both Friends and Subscription system.
I have read about it at few blogs and books but i feel i could not find a very proper implementation for it.

1. **I want that there should be only 1 entry in database corresponding to each relationship**, so i modelled my relationship table with the fields (user_id, friend_id, status, type), where type ={friend, subscriber} and status = {accepted, hold}
2. I want to implement all functions like send_request, accept_request, cancel_request, unfriend, delete_request, subscribe, unsubscribe.
3. Next i want the all functions to be follow abstration rules. Like send_request should function like current_user.send_request(@user) and not like send_request(@user, @friend) and write all the sql there.
4. I believe such an implementation can give me help to extend relationships to more types like "family" "best friends" etc. .

I have looked a lot but couldnt find a proper implementation of facebook style friendship model. Please tell me some resource from where i could get some help or help me with the code if possible. I am posting the code for my User model in the way i started coding it but i feel there could be a better possible solution. Please through some insight. I know this question isnt very to the point and subjective. Admin: Please excuse for violating that rule of Stackoverflow.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,    :trackable, :validatable

 has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

 has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "friend_id",  :class_name =>    "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy

 has_many :direct_friends, :through => :relationships, :conditions => "status =    'accepted'", :source => :friend
 has_many :reverse_friends, :through => :reverse_relationships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'", :source => :user

 has_many :requested_friends, :through => :reverse_relationships,
:source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'hold'", :order => :created_at
 has_many :pending_friends, :through => :relationships, 
:source => :user, :conditions => "status = 'hold'", :order => :created_at

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

 def friends
   direct_friends | reverse_friends
 end

.
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have certainly done your homework. The only thing I can see wrong here is that you're not asking a question. I was going to answer by posting links to BDD and TDD, but that seemed like it would be rude. My advice is, don't try to get everything working at once. Build your way up one step at a time and post a question when something doesn't work or you don't know how to proceed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-networking+ruby-on-rails there's a number of approaches, depending on how much info you need to hang on each "friendship" (and definitely not an easy thing to google).  Also the rails 2 book was pretty good: http://books.google.com/books/about/RailsSpace.html?id=by4hRUMZzJgC